# api in a class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
   {
        show_error("You are not authorized to access this page", 401);
   }
```

I have an api class  `class Api extends CI_Controller` and an another
`class myproject extends` , now if want to use the functions of the api class in myproject class. how can i do . do i have to create an object of api class or just extend the myproject class with parent::api class . please help me as i m not good at oops.

details - i have made a class "class myproject extends ci_controller" which has different functions for user registration and login application. it all works fine using a single controller. But now want to use an api file.which has functions for login. how can i call those functions in api file from "class myproject"

Comment: It's not clear, but I suspect the API class will work better as a library than a Controller

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to extend the API class, as in

```
class Myproject extends Api { ... }
```

but there a few other issues, such as `include_once("Api.php")`, for example, in the Myproject.php file so that the subclass can "see" the superclass declaration.  This [thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTMJ8WwFlz0sJ%3acodeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/74784/%20codeigniter%20extending%20controllers&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) on the codeigniter forums discusses these issues (sorry for the google webcache version but the forums are down for maintenance at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an helper, like the form one and use your method.
Then you can load it:

```
$this->load->helper('api');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't call a function of a controller in a controller unless and until you are inheriting it.

It's better that you create API class as library, instead of a controller.

If you have some restriction to have it as a controller only then use these APIs through curl calls.

But the best way is to have them in helper, if you are accessing them from your own server only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this looks more like a software design problem rather then a real code issue.

CodeIgniter is based on the MVC concept, and the Controller is only meant to build up the page.
You should probably make a library for all the API functionality, and have the controller calling that library and converting the data to JSON or whatever you want it to be converted to.

For myself i apply a simple rule:
Never write/call a Controller method that doesn't generate any form of output.

I recommend you to stick to the CodeIgniter way of coding, and not try to avoid them.